# SSIS finding NULL's and empty fields and renaming them

Tags: replace, ssis, null

I'm trying to find NULL values within my database column with SSIS (2008 R2 Enterprise), but it gives me the following error:

`The expression "FINDSTRING([Copy of jaartext],"",1) > 0" on "output "Opdracht" (552)" evaluated to NULL, but the "component "Conditional Split" (336)" requires a Boolean results.`

I'm trying to `Conditional Split` every options of my database (with the data type string) to a different output, as you see in figure 1 below. Then I'm using a `Derived Column` each of the options to `REPLACE` their value by an integer (see figure 2).

This all works, except for the NULL value. Any tips for me to look up the NULL value, instead of the empty string? I'd really appreciate some help.

[image]
[Figure 1]

[image]
[Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [IsNull](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141184(v=sql.110).aspx) and the ternary operator `(boolean) ?:`

```
IsNull([ColumnName]) ? "-1" : REPLACE([ColumnName], " ", "1")
```

Here, if our column is NULL, then I assign -1. Otherwise, I replace a space with 1

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, that fixed my problem. Although I found a new one.

`ISNULL([Copy of jaartext])` finds all the NULL-valued records and pass them to a derived column, then I use the code you provided to replace the NULL's. However, `FINDSTRING([Copy of jaartext],"",1) > 0` do not find the empty string values, which I'm trying to pass to a derived column as well. Now I'm trying to figure out why the empty string cannot be found. Perhaps you have a quick tip/solution for this as well - will not have to reopen a new question.

Comment: I guess FINDSTRING doesn't work on blank fields. I got the condition to work with: TRIM([Copy of jaartext]) == "" ? "1" : [Copy of jaartext]

Comment: I would generally use something like `len(ltrim([MyColumn])) ==0` to determine whether a string is empty